# Uncaught Error: Angular even after loading ng-route

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting this dreadful error:

```
angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module usersApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngRoute due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngRoute' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong: app.js:

```
(function () {

    var app = angular.module('usersApp',
        ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

      var viewBase = '/';

        $routeProvider
            .when('/users', {
                controller: 'MainController',
                templateUrl: viewBase + 'users/users.html',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })
            .when('/add', {
                controller: 'OrdersController',
                templateUrl: viewBase + 'add/orders.html'
            })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/users' });

    }]);


}());
```

index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Angular App!</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="usersApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <h1>uSers</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="user in users" ng-click="getUsers()" style="background: black; padding: 5px; min-width: 25px; color: white;">
    {{user}}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: can you please use version 1.5.8 in angular route

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to include `angular-route`.
in addition, no need to load 2 different versions of angular. change your main html to this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Angular App!</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="usersApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <h1>uSers</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="user in users" ng-click="getUsers()" style="background: black; padding: 5px; min-width: 25px; color: white;">
    {{user}}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you are missing to include angular.route.js in index.html

Comment: Would you mind showing me how to include it? I thought this script tag was including it: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
`

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>

Comment: path  which you have given is local